# Check image width / height ratio continuously

Tags: javascript

I have this very simple but effective script that adds a class `landscape` or `portrait` to the img according to the width / height ratio.

```
$('img').each(function(){
$(this).addClass(this.width > this.height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait');
});
```

The problem is that the website uses infinite scroll and when the second page is loaded the images won't be affected by the script.

Is there any way I can run the script continuously to check images proportions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a call to this code at the end of code that does the loading

Comment: call your function  in both scroll and resize function and try

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is any way.
Set you function in you onscroll-event

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
   $('img').each(function(){
   $(this).addClass(this.width > this.height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your request there is a way to check it continuously using `setInterval`, however I don't think that is the most efficient solution to a problem like this (for instance you may try and check for an `onchange` event on your body of your HTML). Here is the way you can by using `setInterval`:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('img').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass(this.width > this.height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait');
  });
  console.log("Updated images");
}, 1000 * 2); // Where '2' says it will run every 2 seconds (every 2000 milliseconds)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```